# Velocity - dropdown based on hashmap, display values on selection

Tags: java, velocity, template-engine

I have a `HashMap< String, List< Integer>>`. Is it possible for me to display a dropdown box in velocity based on the String keys in the `HashMap` and when the user makes its selection to display the `List< Integer>` below the dropdown?

Comment: Velocity will just print a static html, may you will have to parse this HashMap with JavaScript and do this DOM manipulation with it.

Answer (score 0):

Velocity is server side, HTML lives in a browser on the client side. When the user interacts with page, Velocity has long since ceased to be executed. So no, you can not use values from the live DOM in Velocity. You can, however, send back the selected value to Velocity:

1. Render the initial HTML page with a `<select>` that lists the top level options, in a `<form>`
2. The user selects something from the `<select>` and submits the form
3. Back on the server, Velocity can then read the selected value from the request and generate a new HTML with the second level options

If you don't want two page loads, you can either use an AJAX request to get just the list of valid values, or you can send the whole map in the first step (hidden in the HTML) and process it clientside with JavaScript.